# Mounting OneDrive on Ubuntu Linux command line

Tags: command-line, mount, drive, microsoft

For some requirement, I need to mount OneDrive instead of Syncing files through onedrive-d. Also, I need need a command line solution to automate something in my scripts. Can anyone help on this ?

I tried to mount it from usual mount command, but failed. Please note, I am not an expert of Linux command line, so please help.

Thanks in advance.

--
Ninad

Comment: The best is using onedriver (it has a GUI). It's perfect. https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver

Answer (score 34):

## Mount OneDrive on Ubuntu

This instruction follows [RCLONE - Microsoft OneDrive](https://rclone.org/onedrive/)

1. Download and install Rclone

---

```
sudo apt install rclone
```

or download the latest one

```
wget https://downloads.rclone.org/v1.42/rclone-v1.42-linux-amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./rclone-v1.42-linux-amd64.deb
```

### **2. Add a new OneDrive remote to Rclone**

```
rclone config
```

- Select the **New remote** option by entering  <kbd>n</kbd> and pressing the  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key:

  ```
    $ rclone config
    Current remotes:

    Name                 Type
    ====                 ====
    mega                 mega

    e) Edit existing remote
    n) New remote
    d) Delete remote
    r) Rename remote
    c) Copy remote
    s) Set configuration password
    q) Quit config
    e/n/d/r/c/s/q> n
  ```
- Enter a name for the new remote, here `onedrive` is used:

  ```
    name> onedrive
  ```
- After pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a list of supported cloud storage services is displayed. You need to select the **Microsoft OneDrive** option by entering its corresponding number ("16" right now but it may change in the future):

  ```
    Type of storage to configure.
    Choose a number from below, or type in your own value
    [snip]
    ... 
    ...
    xx / Microsoft OneDrive
       \ "onedrive"
    ...
    ...
    [snip]
    Storage> onedrive
  ```
- For the next two steps, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering any information since there's no need to enter the Microsoft App Client ID or Secret:

  ```
    Microsoft App Client Id 
    Leave blank normally.
    client_id> 
    Microsoft App Client Secret - leave blank normally.
    client_secret>
  ```
- Choose the OneDrive account type (enter  `b` for Business or `p` for Personal OneDrive accounts):

  ```
    Remote config
    Choose OneDrive account type?
     * Say b for a OneDrive business account
     * Say p for a personal OneDrive account
    b) Business
    p) Personal
    b/p> p
  ```
- Depending on your setup, you'll have to enter auto configuration or manual for the next step. For desktop users, type <kbd>y</kbd>  to use the auto configuration. If you are setting up on a remote or headless machine type <kbd>n</kbd> (you will need to run `rclone config` on a machine with browser access and copy/paste an authentication token later:

  ```
    Use auto config?
     * Say Y if not sure
     * Say N if you are working on a remote or headless machine
    y) Yes
    n) No
    y/n> y
  ```
- If you are mounting on a local machine: A new tab should open in your default web browser, asking you to give Rclone access to your OneDrive account. Allow it and you can close the tab.
  Rclone runs a webserver on your local machine (on port 53682) to retrieve the authentication token. You may need to unblock it temporarily if you use a firewall.
  .
  If setting up a remote or headless machine: rclone will provide a terminal command that you will need to execute on a machine with a web browser. This command will provide you with an authentication key that you should paste into this session. See [these instructions](https://rclone.org/remote_setup/) for more details.
- Now you'll need to check if everything is correct and save the settings by typing <kbd>y</kbd>:

  ```
    [onedrive]
    type = onedrive
    client_id = 
    client_secret = 
    token = {"access_token":"GoKSt5YMioiuCWX1KOuo8QT0Fwy+Y6ZeX7M","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"7OMvoEAO3l*8BbhS2AMxpTbJW0Y6np9cdql!bwEdYAhJ6XBG0tnR0UK","expiry":"2018-07-26T15:15:13.696368366+03:00"}
    --------------------
    y) Yes this is OK
    e) Edit this remote
    d) Delete this remote
    y/e/d> y
  ```
- Exit the Rclone configuration by typing <kbd>q</kbd>:

  ```
   Current remotes:

   Name                 Type
   ====                 ====
   onedrive             onedrive

   e) Edit existing remote
   n) New remote
   d) Delete remote
   r) Rename remote
   c) Copy remote
   s) Set configuration password
   q) Quit config
   e/n/d/r/c/s/q> q
  ```

3. Create a new folder

---

```
mkdir ~/OneDrive
```

4. Mount OneDrive

---

```
rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount onedrive: ~/OneDrive
```

You can stop and unmount it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>  to close Rclone.

5. (Optional) Mount OneDrive on system startup

---

To mount OneDrive on startup, open  Startup Applications, and in Startup Applications click Add.

After clicking Add, use the following:

```
Name:    Rclone OneDrive Mount
Command: sh -c "rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount onedrive: ~/OneDrive"
```

There are other ways of mounting OneDrive automatically, like adding a line in your `/etc/fstab file`, using systemd, etc.

Comment: 2020/04/28 22:56:44 Fatal error: unknown flag: --vfs-cache-mode

Comment: --vfs-cache-mode is a known flag according to the rclone manual! Please add your command line and the name of your drive in the post. In order to see if your rclone configuration is rigth type `rclone lsd <your drive name>: `

Comment: @Tony is correct. That option is not valid and is not in the current man page.

Comment: from man rclone(1) (version v1.50.2): **Limitations** 
       Without the use of “–vfs-cache-mode” this can only write files sequentially, it can only  seek  when  reading.
       This  means  that  many  applications  won’t work with their files on an rclone mount without `–vfs-cache-mode writes` or `–vfs-cache-mode full`.  See the File Caching section for more info.

Comment: This solution works for me, thanks in advance. The only problem is after reboot using the Startup Applications the onedrive does not mount, it has to be manually mounted. Perhaps i'm missing something.

Comment: The best is using onedriver (it has a GUI). It's perfect. https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something.  Can I somehow see the data shared with me in OneDrive by other users, groups, etc.?  Currently I only see my private data in the mounted directory.

Comment: I don't use windows any more (3 years) and the post is very old (4 years).

Answer (score 1):

For any WSL users, it is easy.  Without doing anything at all, I could access OneDrive at

```
/mnt/c/Users/my_user_name/OneDrive/
```

which uses the standard Windows OneDrive and filesystem drivers.

Comment: **It should be noted this answer is applicable ONLY to WSL.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy solution to mount OneDrive in any gnu/linux distribution.

You can use Storage Made Easy (SMEStorage) to mount several providers in one folder. It is free up to 3 providers, but it is not opensource.

You can also use the app provided or mount it via webdav (Nautilus - Connect to server) and use the instructions provided in: [CloudDAV](https://storagemadeeasy.com/CloudDav)

Answer (score 0):

**extra**

If you are on xfce4 (Manjaro)

create  `/home/$(USER)/.onedive.sh` give excute permission

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 3
rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount onedrive: ~/onedrive
```

add `sh /home/$(USER)/.onedive.sh` to start up application

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
onedrive --monitor
```

after proper installation:
https://itslinuxfoss.com/how-to-install-and-use-onedrive-on-ubuntu-20-04/

You can put it in e.g. the Startup apps.

Comment: The best is using onedriver (it has a GUI). It's perfect. https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver

Answer (score 0):

As @Allexj mentioned in [his comment to the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804421/mounting-onedrive-on-ubuntu-linux-command-line#comment2569156_804421) there's also a program called "[onedriver](https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver)", which mounts your OneDrive as a network storage, so it doesn't keep local files synched to the cloud but instead just lists your online files in a local directory of your choosing and downloads them whenever you actually need them. I downloaded onedriver through the [OpenSUSE Build Service](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Ajstaf&package=onedriver), which builds the package for you for Debian, OpenSUSE, Raspbian and Ubuntu and allows you to install them as a matching package for your system.
I tested it and it seems great, especially since my school's OneDrive has 1TB of storage (so I regularly use it to move large files from one computer to another) and with the solution I previously had I had to ensure that my laptop was offline during that time so it wouldn't waste its SSD space on OneDrive.

The package installs two commands, `onedriver` (for command-line access) and `onedriver-launcher` (the GUI for `onedriver`).